# Eigenvalue problem $DD^{+}$ (big) vs $D^{+}D$ (small). Spectral relations.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a complex $N\times M$ matrix $D$, in my case $N\gg M$. I have found that:

1) The biggest $M$ eigenvalues of $DD^{+}$ (size $N\times N$) are equal to those of $D^{+}D$ (size $M\times M$).

2) Find the eigenvectors $v$'s of $D^{+}D$. The matrix $Dv_iv_i^{+}$ is of the size of $D$ and has all the columns proportional to each other. These columns are the $i$th principal components for the corresponding columns of $D$. Being normalized, all the columns become equal and any of them gives the $i$th eigenvector of $DD^{+}$.

Given 1) and 2), one can easily solve a big low-rank partial eigenvalue problem.

Question: can someone give me a reference to a textbook or a paper with the proofs of 1) and 2) and possibly other related statements? Thanks!

Edit:
It is quite trivial that ($\lambda$, $Dv$) is eigen pair of $DD^{+}$ for any eigen pair ($\lambda$, $v$) of $D^{+}D$. But why the spectrum of $D^{+}D$ has to be at the top of the spectrum of $DD^{+}$? Again, a good reference would be appreciated.